# Powershell ParseExact() Military time Convert-DateTime

Tags: .net, datetime, powershell, wmi

I am retrieving WMI win32_process information and trying to convert the CreationDate into something a little more readable

```
$Header = @("__SERVER","Caption","CommandLine","CreationDate","ProcessID")
$processes = Get-WmiObject win32_process -ComputerName theComputer |? {$_.caption -eq "java.exe"} | select $header 
#Format-Date
$processes | % {
        $crdate = $_.CreationDate
        if($crdate -match ".\d*-\d*") {
            $crdate = $crdate -replace $matches[0]," "
            $idate = [System.Int64]$crdate
            $date = [DateTime]::ParseExact($idate,'yyyyMMddhhmmss',$null)
            $_.CreationDate = $date             
        }
    }
```

This function works great, but sometimes fails with the error message: 
`Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."`

I'm aware I am passing in an int, I also tried converting `$idate` to a String and passing that in, but it errored on the same value.

Sample Input:(value of $idate right before ParseExact call)
20130719113954
20130719114700
20130719133000   <---- This fails
20130719053000
20130719060001
20130719134000   <---- This fails

So clearly this function only works before 12:00

My question is how do I get this to recognize military time? Before 12, it will spit me out a great date that looks like `7/19/2013 11:47:00 AM`. How would parse exact know the difference between AM and PM if it does not accept military time?

Note: win32_process originally returns a CreationDate value like `20130719133000.137239-240` But I wasn't able to parse that at all, and I really don't care about milliseconds.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make the format string `yyyyMMddHHmmss`. `hh` is for 12-hour format, `HH` for 24-hour format. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

Comment: Could not find for the life of me how to get military time with milliseconds. Thank you so much for the tip about the HH for the hours!

Answer (score 0):

You most likely figured this out already, but I noticed you had '$*.CreationDate = $date' at the end of the 'if' statement in your foreach loop; Since $*.CreationDate was already declared you could probably eliminate/comment-out that part to avoid possible "Type mismatch" errors.

Comment: Nope sorry, there are no "type mismatch errors" in powershell. its '$_.CreationDate' not '$.CreationDate' ... and creation date isn't something you declare it's just a property of the process type. $_ just means the object in the pipe.. in this instance. $_ refers to each process since I'm am piping $processes to a for each loop. $_.CreationDate just gets the creation date of the current process